# How to use the try/except with Selenium Webdriver when having Exceptions on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying the use a try/except statement to findout if an element exists in the WebDrive or not, if so then run a specific code line,

```
try:
    WebDriver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="..."')
except NoSuchElement:
    ActionToRunInCaseNoSuchElementTrue
else:
    ActionToRunInCaseNoSuchElementFalse
```

but running this code gives an error:

- NameError: name 'NoSuchElement' is not defined

how should the Exception be defined?
Is there any shorter/easier way to check if an element does exist in a web page and run a command if so and another if not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be able to use [required exception](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.common.exceptions) you have to import it first with correct name (`NoSuchElement` -> `NoSuchElementException`):

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    WebDriver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="..."')
except NoSuchElementException:
    ActionToRunInCaseNoSuchElementTrue
```

Comment: Thank you! this is what I was looking for. Btw, didn't find it in any tutorial. God Bless you :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `try except` you can use `find_elements` and check if the returned list has any elements

```
elements = WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class="..."')
if not elements:
    ActionToRunInCaseNoSuchElementTrue
else:
    ActionToRunInCaseNoSuchElementFalse
    # the element is in elements[0]
```

Comment: IMHO, this is the better way to do this. We shouldn't be using exceptions to control logic flow. Exceptions should be exceptional...

Comment: @JeffC, Maybe in `Java`, `C++` or other programming languages "Look before you leap" idiomatic practice is more popular, but exceptions are handled more efficiently in `Python` that's why "ask forgiveness not permission" is more preferable idioma in `Python`...IMHO my answer is better :)

Comment: @Andersson I'd be interested in someone [**looking at you :)**] doing a simple performance test between these two snippets. I bet that the exception method (yours) is actually slower but probably on the order of a handful of ms. For me, this has nothing to do with performance, it's just simply that exceptions should be exceptional. They should be used to trap errors and prevent catastrophic failures, not used for control flow when you have another (very simple) option. I know not everyone agrees with me and I'm OK with that.

Comment: using exceptions for flow control is considered very pythonic.